# React Native: Android couldn't find "libj2v8utils.so"

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, libraries

I have a tricky problem with Android builds. The framework I use is React Native 0.61.5.

I have to use a particular SDK which needs to use a library called **libj2v8utils.so**. After some deepening I noticed that this library should be accompanied with another one: **libj2v8.so**.

The **libj2v8.so** library is always present in the `<root>/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/arm64-v8a` path (all architectures), while the **libj2v8utils.so** library is present only for the `arm64-v8a` architecture.

Unfortunately I am not an expert in the Android environment and what concerns the project configurations with Maven, build.gradle and so on. However, I have made a few attempts like the following:

```
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/*.so'
    }
```

or

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jnilibs']
        }
    }
```

All without success.

The details of the error are as follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.my.custom.sdk.common.internal.core.utils.J2V8Utils
...
can't get JS engine attributes
MyCustomSDK: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.bundle123==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/my.bundle123==/lib/arm, /data/app/my.bundle123==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libj2v8utils.so"
```

Finally, in the application logs I see:

```
authentication failed Internal error occurred (TypeError: t.getData is not a function)
```

The following screenshots show the libraries generated for the different architectures:

[image]

When I build the APK by `npx react-native run-android` I don't notice anything in particular. How can I solve this issue?